# Disabling HTML button with JavaScript when text reaches min/max size

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, click

Sorry if the title doesn't explains well, I have this page, with two buttons and a text block, one is for increasing the size of that text and the other for decrease it.
I want to disable each button when text reaches maximum or minimum size. For example:

Click "Bigger" button, if text reaches max size, disable the button.
Click "Smaller" button, if text reaches min size, disable the button.

I tried using the next if statement inside the onclick function:

```
    if(currentSize== "66.6667pt"){bigger.disabled=true;}
```

where 66.6667pt was the size the text reached before staying fixed. The other case, the minimun size was 6.75pt.

I don't know if there is a better way of verifying if a text reached its min/max size, but this way I'm doing it doesn't work, "bigger" button is getting disabled the second time the text reached 66.6667pt, "smaller" button never gets disabled.

This is the entire html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
<head lang="es">
  <title>Find Bug Script</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  <style>
  </style>
  <script>
     window.onload=function(){ 

          var smaller = document.getElementById("smaller");
          var hello = document.getElementById("hello");
          if(!hello.style.fontSize){hello.style.fontSize="12pt";} 
          var factor=0.75;
          bigger.onclick=function(){

             var currentSize=hello.style.fontSize;
            if(currentSize== "66.6667pt"){bigger.disabled=true;}
             var csz = parseInt(currentSize.replace("24pt", ""));
             if(csz > 60) return;
             csz/=factor;
             hello.style.fontSize= csz+"pt";


          }
          smaller.onclick=function(){

             if(hello.style.fontSize== "6.75pt"){smaller.disabled=true;}
             var currentSize=hello.style.fontSize;
             var csz = parseInt(currentSize.replace("24pt", ""));
             if(csz <= 6) return;
             csz*=factor;
             hello.style.fontSize= csz+"pt";
          }

     };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type=button value="Bigger" id="bigger"/>
    <input type=button value="Smaller" id="smaller" />
    <h1 id="hello" maxlength="5">¡Hello!</h1>
</body>
```

This is from my first HTML/JS class so, let's try to learn it well.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button isn't getting disabled because the condition `currentSize== "66.6667pt"` is never true. It seems like you're handling the disabled state twice, because in addition to disabling the button, your function returns early if the size is less than 60:

```
if(csz > 60) return;
```

So after clicking a few times, your size eventually gets to be 65.33333333333333pt, which prevents it from getting bigger on subsequent clicks, but it never satisfies the condition that disables the button.

You have two different things you consider to be the max allowable size: 60 in one place, and 66.6667 in another. Try defining it once and using that in both places:

```
var maxSize=60;
bigger.onclick=function(){
   var currentSize=hello.style.fontSize;
   if(parseFloat(currentSize)> maxSize){bigger.disabled=true;}
   var csz = parseInt(currentSize.replace("24pt", ""));
   if(csz > maxSize) return;
   csz/=factor;
   hello.style.fontSize= csz+"pt";
}
```

Here's a [working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/CodyRank/b79Kt/). Try doing the same thing for minSize yourself. You could also try re-enabling the button once they've shrunk the text again.

Comment: Thank you for the idea of re-enabling the buttons, worked fine!

Answer (score 3):

Performing math directly on the fontSize attribute is a little messy.

Instead of trying read out the text size every time, I would just keep a "stepper" variable in my javascript code which keeps track of what font-size "step" you're on. Then I would plug the stored value in the stepper into some formula to come up with the final font size. To constrain the size, you can make sure the "step" is above or below certain values.

Something like this:

```
var factor = 0.75;
var step   = 0;

bigger.onclick = function() {
    step++;
    step = Math.min(step, 4) // Step can never go above 4
    reloadText();
}

smaller.onclick = function() {
    step--;
    step = Math.max(step, -4) // Step can never go below -4
    reloadText();
}

function reloadText() {
    // 14 is the default size, in points.
    // If step is equal to zero, there will be no change in size.
    // If step is below zero, the font will be smaller.
    // If step is above zero, the font will be larger.
    var size = 14 + (step*factor); 
    hello.style.fontSize= size+"pt";

    if (step >= 4) {
        // Disable "bigger" button
    } else {
        // Enable "bigger" button
    }

    if (step <= -4) {
        // Disable "smaller" button
    } else {
        // Enable "smaller" button
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do :

```
if(parseInt(currentSize)> 66){bigger.disabled=true;}
```

If at least I understand your question.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work with parseInt because text size goes float, tried with parseFloat tho, and worked the same as before

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers @aapierce and @cody, followed cody's answer, it worked, just modified the if statements this way:

in bigger.onclick(), if text reaches max size, disable "bigger" button, but enable "smaller" button

```
 if(parseFloat(currentSize)> maxSize){bigger.disabled=true; smaller.disabled=false;}
```

in smaller.onclick() is the opposite:

```
if(parseFloat(currentSize)<= minSize){smaller.disabled=true; bigger.disabled=false;}
```

Will try to follow aapierce answer to get more practice on this subject